# Adding Using Reduce Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a very simple problem. I wanted to get the total gross using reduce function.
My problem is that its a string but I already added `+` to make it a number. I wonder that output is still `NaN`?

```js
const hello = [
    {
        "gross": "391.50",
    },
    {
        "gross": "489.80",
    }
]

const final = hello.reduce((prev, cur) => Number(prev.gross) + Number(cur.gross), 0);

console.log(final, 'FINAL')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prev` is the running total, not an object, there's no `prev.gross`.

```js
const hello = [{
    "gross": "391.50",
  },
  {
    "gross": "489.80",
  }
]

const final = hello.reduce((prev, cur) => prev + Number(cur.gross), 0);

console.log(final, 'FINAL')
```

Comment: is `Number` or `+` better?

Comment: The difference is negligible. `Number` is more readable IMHO.